# Identify category for combination of words from categories of component words

Tags: probability, classification, likelihood

I have the following matrix:

```
                   category
                  I    II   III
              1  70   300     5 
   word       2  20   400    45
              3  10   300     0
```

It shows the number of times that a word_i appears in a phrase of category j, for example, word_1 appears 300 times in category_II.   I would like to know the probability of a given phrase to be of category I, II, or III. E.g. if the phrase consist of word_1 and word_2.

Two approaches I tried to calculate the probability of the phrase to be of category I:

1. 70/(70+300+5) = 0.186
2. normalization for each category -> 0.7/(0.7+0.3+0.1) = 0.64

In the first case I am biased by the large number of case that fall into category II. In the second, I ignore totally that I am (should be) able to predict case of category II since I do have a lot of statistics.

**Goal**: I would like to have a classifier that avoids being fooled by the large statistics of category II, while being precise when predicting category II. My gut feeling is that I need some measure likelihood here.

Comment: It seems to me that the use of words is not independent, & so the probability of any particular *combination* of words will need to be estimated separately from data, rather than built up from estimated components.